# Typeconverter over the property of the enum

Tags: c#, enums, typeconverter

I have `Typeconverter` for `Enum`:

```
 public class MyEnumConverter: TypeConverter
    {
        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
```

If I put it over the property of the enum, it does not work.

```
        private MY_ENUM _myProp;
        [TypeConverter(typeof(MyEnumConverter))]
        public MY_ENUM MyProp
        {
            get { return _myProp; }
            set
            {
                if (_myProp != value)
                {
                    _myProp= value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProp");
                }
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to put `Typeconverter` just over the Enum itself?

**What do I do if I want that Converter will only work on a particular instance of the Enum?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you shoud implement [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) and use it in the binding expression for this particular property.

Comment: The use of this variable is in c #, not in wpf.

Comment: @Hodaya Shalom, modify your question with code example on how you want to use this property then. Atm it is not clear, what are you trying to do

Comment: It only works when I put the converter over the enum, but I want the converter will be just over the variable.

Comment: @Hodaya Shalom, show your enum and full implementation of your converter then. And edit your original question, so it is clear, that you are asking about property grid.